# `type -a ls` produce three identical ls address

Tags: bash

When I check the `ls` command, there exist a series of them:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
ls is /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
ls is /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

If view them from the folder

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ | grep "ls"
false
ls
```

It's single one ls command rather than three.

What's the reason, type -a produce three identical `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Debian Stretch, which distro are you using.

Comment: I installed Gnu/bash on macos @maulinglawns

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` appears in your `PATH` more than once, so [`type -a`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type) looks at it three times and reports that it found `ls` there for each one.

You can inspect your PATH (`echo "$PATH"`) to see that, or manipulate it to replicate and modify the behaviour:

```
PATH=/bin:/bin type -a ls
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/bin type -a ls
```

Somewhere in your environment setup the variable is being set more than once, possibly from having run an automated script that's added an extra line `PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH` a few times over.

Comment: Or, the addition to `PATH` has been done manually, several times, on the command line.  Homebrew on macOS does not modify `.bashrc`.